# Authenticate user with a specific hosted domain (hd) in Flask with Oauth2

Tags: python, flask, google-authentication

Hi this is my current python code for authentification in my web app.

```
auth_flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
                                client_secret=AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
                                scope=AUTH_PLUS_SCOPE,
                                redirect_uri=AUTH_CALLBACK_URI)

AUTH_ARGS = {
    'error': fields.Str(),
    'code': fields.Str()
}


@auth_api.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_auth_uri():
    if current_user and current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(LOGIN_PATH)
    else:
        auth_uri = auth_flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return redirect(auth_uri)


@auth_api.route('/oauth2callback', methods=['GET'])
@use_kwargs(AUTH_ARGS)
def oauth2_callback(error, code):
    if error:
        return redirect(url_for('login'), code=HTTPStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT)
    else:
        try:
            authenticate(code)
            return redirect(LOGIN_PATH)
        except Unauthorized:
            raise APIError(HTTPStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, AUTH_FAILED_MESSAGE)


@auth_api.route('/me', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def get_current_user():
    return jsonify(current_user.serialized)


@auth_api.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))



def authenticate(code):
    try:
        credentials = _get_credentials(code)
        user = User.get_or_create(credentials)
        login_user(user)
    except FlowExchangeError:
        raise Unauthorized()


def _get_credentials(code):
    return auth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
```

However, right now, my application is accepting login from any google account adress. I would like to restrict access to login for user with a specified domain like abc@harvard.edu. I've seen some answers with hd parameters but I have no clue how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hd parameter can be set by appending it to the `auth_uri` as follows

```
auth_uri = GOOGLE_AUTH_URI
auth_uri = auth_uri + '?hd=' + 'example.com'

auth_flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
                            client_secret=AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
                            scope=AUTH_PLUS_SCOPE,
                            redirect_uri=AUTH_CALLBACK_URI,
                            auth_uri=auth_uri,
                            )
```

However in my experience the hd parameter does not restrict users with different email addresses from logging in. You should always validate the credentials.

```
def authenticate(code):
    try:
        credentials = _get_credentials(code)
        if not credentials.id_token['email'].endswith('@example.com')
            # abort(401)
            raise Unauthorized()
        user = User.get_or_create(credentials)
        login_user(user)
     except FlowExchangeError:
        raise Unauthorized()
```

Comment: Excellent, I had already succeeded by adding the second part of your code in authenticate but it's always better to validate it twice. Thanks for the answer. I will upvote your answer as soon as I get enough reputation!

Comment: Do you know why my question is not upvoted? I am trying to ask good question but nobody upvote it.